# Giving C++ Application a HTTP Web Server Functionality

Tags: c++, web-services, http

I have a C++ app and looking for a library that would make it a HTTP Server that's able to serve static files as well as perform very simple tasks. The only constraint is that it must be Cross-platform.

What are my options.

Clarify: I need a web interface for my application. This application is a background program that does other tasks. I want to provide a way so you can access http://localhost:9999/performtask or http://localhost:9999/viewstatus

clarification2: something like this http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/

Comment: Your question really isn't clear. do you have some functionality that you want to serve via the web?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [a question which has since been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library), I asked:

> I'm looking for a well-written, flexible library written in C or C++ (I'm writing my apps in C++) that can be used to embed an relatively simple HTTP server into my applications. Ultimately I will use this for application monitoring and control.
>
> There are a number of great client-side libraries (e.g. libwww, neon, curl) but I'm struggling to find a good solution for the server-side. I'm sure other folks have done this before, so I'd love to hear what folks have done and what has worked and what hasn't.

I ended up choosing [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/).

Comment: Exactly what I need (points++ for Mongoose doing threading) Thanks!

Comment: or use [Civetweb](https://github.com/bel2125/civetweb) if you can't use GPL - this is based on the original, MIT licensed version of Mongoose.

Comment: Question link has been deleted, please edit the text.

Comment: @AliBigdeli fixed.  Kept the link in case the question is undeleted (I've requested it be), but pasted the body here as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wt library](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) does exactly this. Recommended, especially if your user interface gets more complex.

Comment: +1 Wt is best library I have found.  Good example code. Bad documentation. Easy if you have Qt background.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished the same thing you want to accomplish by using the HTTP Server example for boost::asio.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

This was a perfect solution for me, because my project was already dependent on boost::thread and boost::asio, so the HTTP Server example code fit into my application and I could easily have complete control over its threading behavior. I just copied HTTP Server example files into my project and customized the request-response logic.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought !

Why don't you convert your c++ application code to a native/extension module for any of the following http servers.

- Apache Webserver
- IIS 7.0 native module
- Nginx
- LightHttpd

All the above servers except IIS are cross platform.

Maybe building an extension module would yield a better output and the above server are very scalable too.

Answer (score 0):

I am partial to the [poco library](http://pocoproject.org) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Snorkel it is a light weight fast cross-platform embedded/application server SDK that allows you to quickly add web interfaces to any C/C++ application.  Its free and can be found at http://sites.google.com/site/snorkelembedded.  Its faster than mongoose.

Answer (score -1):

Qt framework have buildin webkit. have a lookinto that.

Answer (score -2):

Java would be a better choice for a cross-platform solution plus it has good web services apis. Take a look at Netbeans it is a good way to get started.

Comment: This would be a good route to take, except the application is already written, it has to be C or C++